# How to get values from price range slider?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range Im using this range slider but i have problem to get values in controller. In blade i have this:

```
<input type="text" id="amount" readonly name="price" >
```

This is my js:

```
$(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;

    // do some validation on the hash here
    hash && $('ul.nav a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');

    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 30000,
        values: [ 0, 30000 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] + " CHF");
        }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
    " - " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) + " CHF" );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the Javascript so the slide function writes the value to two different inputs which can be easily read by the server.
This can be done in the `slide` event where you are now adding the values together and adding a currency.

Something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="minval" id="minval" />
<input type="text" name="maxval" id="maxval" />

$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    values: [ 75, 300 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#minval").val(ui.values[0]);
        $("#maxval").val(ui.values[1]);
    }
});
```

Now you will be able to get the values as `$request->minval` and `$request->maxval`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Request` object as usual:

```
public function someMethod(Request $request)
{
    $price = $request->price;
```

If it's empty, then there is some problem with JS code.

Comment: i get this:"6124 - 30000 CHF" and how can i get then first and secon parameter so then i can use it in query?

Comment: @None it's impossible to help you until you show JS code you use.